# Open Windows Explorer from Javascript

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-browser

I want to open a file directory on the windows explorer by clicking a button in my application.

Note:
1. I do not want a file browser/web viewer, but the Windows Explorer (Windows+E)
2. My application does not run on a web browser (e.g. Chrome, Explorer), but a batch file. So whether Chrome blocks local folder browsing is irrelevant to me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... Simply run shell script on your JS code!
Node.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;

var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform); // possible outcomes -> 'darwin', 'freebsd', 'linux', 'sunos' or 'win32'

exec((isWin?'start ':'open ') + name,
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I suspect this can also be a work around for launching client side applications.

Comment: Now, does this solution require node js to be installed on every client side for this to work? Or can it be served from the server side?